# Muilti Select Combo Box To String Convert In Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a muilti select combo box like below.

i need to store all the select items like this string `Very Cold :+: Very Hot`

```
<select name="MilkShake" id="MilkShake" onchange="changeselectItems(this,'MilkShake');">
    <option value="Very Cold">Very Cold </option>
    <option value="Very Hot">Very Hot </option>
    <option value="Med Size">Med Size </option>
    <option value="Large Size">Large Size </option>
    <option value="1 by 2">1 by 2 </option>
    <option value="1 by 4">1 by 4 </option>
    <option value="2 by 3">2 by 3 </option>
    <option value="Glass">Glass </option>
</select>
```

i have tried using this function

```
function changeselectItems(ref,miniproname)
{
var ref = ref.value;
    var newf = Array();
    alert(ref);
for(var i=0;i<newexampleitem.length;i++)
    {
        newf['sel'] = ref[i];
    }   

}
```

Comment: Your `changeselectItems()` is confusing. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: i have a muiltiple select box i need to make a string like this `Very Cold :+: Very Hot` with all the selected value

Comment: Where are you putting the generated string? You didn't make use of `miniproname` in your function, and `newexampleitem` is undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this

HTML

```
<select name="MilkShake" multiple id="MilkShake" 
onblur = "changeselectItems()">
    <option value="Very Cold">Very Cold </option>
    <option value="Very Hot">Very Hot </option>
    <option value="Med Size">Med Size </option>
    <option value="Large Size">Large Size </option>
    <option value="1 by 2">1 by 2 </option>
    <option value="1 by 4">1 by 4 </option>
    <option value="2 by 3">2 by 3 </option>
    <option value="Glass">Glass </option>
</select>​
```

JS

```
function changeselectItems() {
    var selVal = "";
    var selObj = document.getElementById("MilkShake");

    for (i = 0; i < selObj.options.length; i++) {
        if (selObj.options[i].selected) {
            if (selVal != "") {
                selVal = selVal + " :+: " + selObj.options[i].value;
            } else {
                selVal = selObj.options[i].value;
            }

        }
    }

    alert(selVal);
}​
```

**[Working DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/L5LGq/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to add the "multiple" attribute to your  tag like this: . This enables you to select multiple items by holding down the CTRL key.

Here is my solution for you:

```
    <html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <form name="SelectForm">
            <select multiple name="MilkShake" id="MilkShake" onchange="changeselectItems(this);">
                <option value="Very Cold">Very Cold </option>
                <option value="Very Hot">Very Hot </option>
                <option value="Med Size">Med Size </option>
                <option value="Large Size">Large Size </option>
                <option value="1 by 2">1 by 2 </option>
                <option value="1 by 4">1 by 4 </option>
                <option value="2 by 3">2 by 3 </option>
                <option value="Glass">Glass </option>
            </select>
        </form>

        <script>
        function changeselectItems(el)
        {
            var myForm = document.forms.SelectForm;
            var data = "";
            for(i = 0; i < myForm.MilkShake.length; i++)
            {
                if(myForm.MilkShake[i])
                {
                    if(myForm.MilkShake[i].selected)
                    {
                        //here are all the selected items
                        if(data != "") data+= " : ";
                        data+= myForm.MilkShake[i].value;
                    }
                }
            }

            alert(data);
        }
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: i want to merge all the selected value into one string